# Why is HashSet solution to finding unique characters slow?

Tags: java

I made a O(n^2) and O(n) solution to finding unique characters and was curious to really see the performance difference. I would have expected the `HashSet` solution would have blew the O(n^2) solution out of the water, but it's actually slower than just doing nested loops.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

class AllUnique
{
    // O(n^2) solution
    static boolean isUnique(String str)
    {
        int ind = 0;
        boolean unique = true;
        while (ind != str.length())
        {
            int inner_ind = ind + 1;
            while (inner_ind != str.length())
            {
                if (str.charAt(ind) == str.charAt(inner_ind))
                {
                    unique = false;
                }
                inner_ind++;
            }
            ind++;
        }
        return unique;
    }

    // O(n) solution
    static boolean isUnique2(String str)
    {
        HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            set.add(str.charAt(i));
        }
        return set.size() == str.length();
    }
}
```

With a really simple driver that tests millisecond differences:
public class Program {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stringArr = new String[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            stringArr[i] = "wefwefwefwefwefalkjegb";
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            AllUnique.isUnique(stringArr[i]);
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            AllUnique.isUnique2(stringArr[i]);
        }
        long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime2-startTime2) + "ms");
    }
}
```

Does hashing `Character` objects really take that long?

Usually, the nested loop solution is about 5-10ms faster than the HashSet solution.

Comment: Use a proper benchmarking tool. Anything measured without it can be discarded.

Comment: Note that your test string is rather short, try performance measuring with varying string lengths and the result might be totally different. Also, `isUnique` can be optimized by breaking the loop and returning early as soon as `unique == false`. Same can be done for you second implementation by observing `add` method's return.

Comment: @qqilihq That actually seems to be it. I definitely should use a proper benchmarking tool, but at least I learned there is a slight overhead using HashSet which eventually becomes faster the longer the strings are.

Comment: Neither loop has been optimised. I would always try to compare optimal code such as when you know it's false, return false.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Doh. Yeah that improves performance of both loops by a significant number. Thanks!

Comment: For string with length 29 your N2 algorithm executes 29*29 "instructions", HashSet on the other hand executes 29 complex instructions that involve computing hash code of string, boxing unboxing characters, managing internal array. Try to measure performance on string longer than 32K and you will see difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n) faster then O(n^2) on infinite set of data. In practice it is not necessary true for finite values of n. Your size is not big enough to see the difference. Try to make stringArr[i] biger. Like 1000 long.

If you want practical advise replace set.add(str.charAt(i)) with

```
if(set.contains(str.charAt(I)) return false;
set.add(str.charAt(i));
```

Comment: I would rather check for `set.add`'s result. If it's `false`, the element was already in the set. This avoids the additional `contains` check.

Answer (score 1):

One thing which is unfair in your benchmark is that HashSet does not operate on the same entities as your nested loops code. [Java autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) wraps the primitive `char` values to `Character` objects. Which incurs additional costs like GC and lookups in the built in the built in cache for some of those.

Another is benchmarking is tricky to get right. One of the cool tools is [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). It has a lot of examples in the wild e.g. on the maintainers [blog](https://shipilev.net/).